# Condition(s) for weak-star closedness in $B(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness, weak-lp-spaces

Let $A\subseteq B(H)$ be a non-empty bounded closed convex subset of $B(H)$, where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Is there conditions (or equivalent conditions) for $A$ to be

weak-* closed?

Thanks